# How can i get relation with nestjs-typeorm-paginate

Tags: angular, datatable, nestjs

I'm trying to use `nestJs` with angular and `data-table`.

I had `return await this.repo.find({relations: ['device_']})`,
but if I want to use pagination, I have to use

```js
return await paginate<Display>(this.repo, options);
```

How can I get relations in here?
Options don't include a `relations` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
return await paginate<Display>(this.repo, options, {relations:['device_']});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's currently not a way to do that with the currently setup. You could add an eager relationship in your entity or use a query builder like so

#### Option 1

```js
@Entity()
export class ExampleEntity {

  @OneToMany(t => SomethingEntity, something => something.example, {eager: true})
  something: SomethingEntity[];

}
```

#### Option 2

query builder

```js
return paginate<Display>(this.repo.createQueryBuilder().leftJoinAndSelect('something', 's', 's.id = display.somethingId'), {limit, page});
```

To be honest. I didn't think of using relations with this. Maybe instead of the third parameter being findConditions it should allow you to enter the relations.

> However I've come across issues with left join many to many relations with the pagination method so I've had to rehydrate my relations for each item. I might rethink the pagination method. I did build it really quickly to stop repetitive implementation. When I find some time (which looks unlikely) I'll reimplement this method.